# How to design multiple producers from single source in Reactor Java?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am a beginner in a Project Reactor in Java. I can't understand how I should design the situation when I use same source (e.g. send same message) to different producers. So one source = multiple outputs. Could someone explain me how to achieve that?

My best try is:

```
  private Mono<String> main() {
    return Mono.just("simple message")
        .map(msg -> {
          firstProducer.send(msg);
          return msg;
        })
        .map(msg -> {
          secondProducer.send(msg);
          return msg;
        });
  }
```

Comment: you could read up on event-driven development. Put your message (event) on a bus (queue) and have all possible producers check said queue to see if there is something on it that concerns that producer.

Comment: This is very simplified situation. In the real case you usually make some transformation and mappings between consuming and producing that are common for multiple producers. Therefore I would like to stick with one consumer as it is described.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @kaimada and you assume that can't be done using event-driven development .... because?

Comment: I don't assume that it can't be done. I even know that it can. But I am trying to understand if the reactor is capable of handling the situation that I described. It is a question to help me understand limitations and capabilities of the project reactor itself.